# How do I replace a word from a string without using .replace() method as I want the word to be removed only once

Tags: python, string

For example: I have a list `a = ["john", "jack", "mike"]`, and a string like `s = jackmikejohnjackjack"` and I want to append all the names from this string to a new list like `b = ["jack", "mike", "john", "jack", "jack"]`,
as you may have noticed **duplicates** also need to be appended,
I have tried someting like :

```
a = ["john", "jack", "mike"]
s = "jackmikejohnjackjack"
b = []
for item in a:
   if item in s:
      b.append(item)
```

but this will only return `b = ['john', 'jack', 'mike']`, Also can't use `s.replace(item, "")` after appending the name to b as it will give same answer

Comment: According to your script for loop is repeating for three times. So once the list is iteration is completed the program will stop.Can you try using the 'substring' . Take the sting s and find the substring and check the substring is exists in the list.if it's there add it in the list or dont add it.

Comment: Does the order matter in your result string? What if you got something like `['john', 'jack', 'jack', 'jack', 'mike']` would that be a problem?

Comment: why without using `replace()` is there any reason?

Comment: @user32882 No the order doesn't matter and thnaks your answer is what I needed!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order doesn't matter, You could use `re.findall`:

```
import re

a = ["john", "jack", "mike"]
s = "jackmikejohnjackjack"
b = []

for item in a:
    result = re.findall(item, s)
    for subitem in result:
        b.append(item)

print(b)
```

Which would output:

```
['john', 'jack', 'jack', 'jack', 'mike']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that we always have the names that appear then this code can do what you ask for:

```py
>> a = ["john", "jack", "mike"]
>> s = "jackmikejohnjackjack"
>> b = []

>> while s:
       for name in a:
           if s.startswith(name):
               b.append(name)
               s = s[len(name):]
               break

>> print(b)
['jack', 'mike', 'john', 'jack', 'jack']
```